# how can I get and use the construction options types of a class?

Tags: typescript

I'm building a react component library and would like the possible props of a component to match the construction options for a class defined in a 3rd party type definition.

for example there is an `Annotation` class here: https://github.com/wsmd/mapkit-typescript/blob/master/mapkit/mapkit.Annotation.d.ts#L9

and I'd like to get the construction options from here: https://github.com/wsmd/mapkit-typescript/blob/master/mapkit/mapkit.Annotation.d.ts#L160 to use in my component.

My current assumption is that this isn't possible without the interface being exported, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the type with a little generic type magic.

When given a class type (something that implements a `new` with some parameters), this type references an array of all the constructor elements.

```
type ConstructorParameters<T> = T extends new(... args: infer U) => any ? U : never;
```

It's used like this:

```
type AnnotationParams = ConstructorParameters<typeof Annotation>;
```

Then you can get the specific parameter type you want (index 2) like this:

```
// Note that since the parameter is optional, we use the builtin NonNullable around it to remove the `| undefined` part
type AnnotationConstructorParameters = NonNullable<AnnotationParams[2]>;
```